# leave a mandatory checkbox using a list of items populated with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, logic, ngfor

I have an array with items, and with that I populate an ngFor that it shows me my list of items with my checkboxes, I need to make a validation that leaves at least one of these items mandatory.

An example is = if one checkbox is CHECKED and the other is UNCHECKED, I can't uncheck the checkbox that is CHECKED, I need to leave disabled only the one that was checked, I can only uncheck it, if I CHECK my checkbox that was unchecked, so it gets enabled and so on.

I tried this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList"\>
<input type="checkbox" [checked\]="item.checked" (change)="itemSelected($event, item)" [disabled]="notSelectCheck">
```

```
itemSelected(value, level ) {
level.checked = value.target.checked

const valuesChecked = this.dataList.filter((dt) =\> dt.checked).length;

valuesChecked \< 2 ? (this.notSelectCheck = true) : (this.notSelectCheck = false)

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but it sort sounds like you want radio buttons.

Comment: So you want the user to select any number of checkboxes, but always keep one checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will keep the last checkbox always checked, and allow you to check as many ones as you want. You just need to count the number of checked elements and use preventDefault() if the total ones checked==1:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index">
  <input
    name="elem{{ i }}"
    id="elem{{ i }}"
    [(ngModel)]="element.checked"
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="element.checked"
    (click)="checkElement($event, i)"
  />
  <label for="elem{{ i }}">{{ element.text }}</label>
</div>
```

.ts

```
elements: any = [
    {
      checked: true,
      text: 'Element 1',
    },
    {
      checked: true,
      text: 'Element 2',
    },
    {
      checked: true,
      text: 'Element 3',
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      text: 'Element 4',
    },
  ];

  checkElement(e: any, index: number) {
    //checks if the user is checking or unchecking a checkbox
    if (!e.target.checked) {
      //if the user unchecked a checkbox, then I count the number of checked checkboxes
      let totalChecked = 0;
      for (let checked of this.elements) {
        if (checked.checked) {
          totalChecked = totalChecked + 1;
        }
      }
      //if the number of checked checkboxes is 1, then I cancel the uncheck action with e.preventDefault(), and reassign true to the unchecked value.
      if (totalChecked == 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.elements[index].checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: very good, it really worked, that's what I wanted... but could you try to explain me the logic of the method? please

Comment: Sure Jeffen. Let me edit the code and place some remarks to help you understand better.

Comment: Please read my remarks on my original post. Happy coding!

Comment: `const totalChecked=this.elements.filter(x=>x.checked).length` and **never**, **never** use [checked] and [(ngModel)] in the same tag. NgModel yet say to the checkbox if is checked or not